# SSL Warranty - Meaningless?

Tags: https, security-certificate, protection

Lots of SSL seem to come with a warranty:

```
Extended Validation, Green Address Bar
40-bit minimum to 256-bit encryption
USD $100,000 warranty
VeriSign Trust™ Seal and services
```

Has anyone in history ever managed to claim on the warranty?  Are they just a gimmick?  Should it affect my purchasing choice?

Comment: I hate the way SSL certificate products have become bloated with this kind of junk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the SSL warranty is for the end user and that if the SSL issuer issued the cert to a fraudulent site that stole the end users money or identity they would pay out.

Comment: Not according to the Verisign site.

Comment: So the fraud site would have to request the same cert from *your issuer* and then take customers money (which they could make a chargeback through VISA/Mastercard for anyway).  Seems meaningless to me.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Verisign website](http://www.verisign.com/ssl/buy-ssl-certificates/compare-ssl-certificates/index.html), which calls the warranty "Netsure":

> NetSure® protects *certificate holders* against certain losses resulting from breach by VeriSign of the warranties included in your VeriSign SSL Certificate.

Who knows what that really means.